# Frame border disappears when focus is lost on window

Tags: python, tkinter, frame, tkinter-canvas

I have a tkinter window from which I open another window. This window contains a `Frame` which is located inside a `Canvas`. I'm going to make a picture from the window contents but the problem is that the frame border deactivates itself when the focus isn't on the window or I click the meant button for that and therefore is not present in the picture (this happens only in the real code).

In this example the frame border isn't visible after the window is created. By clicking the "Save" button which has no function here, it becomes visible. When the focus is lost on this window the frame disappears but is activated again after clicking somewhere in this window.

I have not the slightest idea why the frame border should behave like this at all. Is there a way to constantly display it?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def open():
    window = tk.Toplevel()

    canvas = tk.Canvas(window, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
    canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)

    frame = tk.Frame(canvas, bg="red")
    frame.config(highlightthickness=5, highlightcolor="black")
    frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

    text = tk.Label(frame, text="Text")
    text.grid(row=0, column=0)

    save_button = ttk.Button(frame, text="Save")
    save_button.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=1, pady=5)

root = tk.Tk()
open_button = ttk.Button(root, command=lambda: [open()], text="Open")
open_button.grid(row=0, column=0)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try adding `highlightbackground="black"` as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `highlightthickness` and `highlightcolor` options are doing exactly what they are designed to do: they only appear when the frame has the focus. It is not designed to be the border of the frame, but rather an indicator of when the frame  has focus.

If you want a permanent border then you should use `borderwidth` and `relief` options, and/or put your frame inside another frame that uses any color you want for the border color.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification about the highlightfunctions. I managed to get it to work with setting `relief="solid"`, too. Otherwise the border isn't shown. But I don't understand your suggestion with the second frame. Do you mean if I want the border to be any other color than black, I have to create a second frame with a background color which is bigger so it overlaps and shows this color as a border?

Comment: @Plantz: yes, exactly. The color of the border is computed based off of the color of the frame. If you want a custom color you can use another frame as a sort of wrapper around your existing frame.